# Sqlite3 : How to get a new group from SUM() and Group By query in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

Table name = 'serie'

```
msgid   data         enabled    size
-----------------------------------------
6937    2020-04-11      YES     577050141
6938    2020-04-11      YES     545559975
6939    2020-04-11      NO      604904889
6940    2020-04-11      NO      599541021


msgid   = row's id
data    = row's date
enabled = 'NO' -> I don't need it ; 'YES' -> I need it
size    = file's size in bytes


cursor = await db.execute("SELECT msgId,data,SUM(size) FROM serie WHERE enabled=? AND data=? GROUP BY data HAVING SUM(size) <= 1122610116",('YES',data,))
row = await cursor.fetchone()
print (row)
```

This code gets sum of 'size' for each rows with enabled = 'YES' , data = '2020-04-11' AND
it must be less or equal to 1122610116 bytes

for example :
that code sum the size of 6937 and 6938 msgId
but How I get '6937' and '6938' from that query.
If I use 'fetchall()' I get only the first msgId (6937). I need every msgId value

Thank you

Comment: As you're grouping by `data` and are wanting to sum over those records, it only returns one line for each group, which can only have the a single identifier. You likely need to run a second query that doesn't group over data, but just selects the ids from the correct records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a `GROUP BY` clause, use SUM() window function in a subquery:

```
SELECT msgId
FROM (
  SELECT msgId, SUM(size) OVER (PARTITION BY data) sum_size
  FROM serie
  WHERE enabled=? AND data=? 
)
WHERE sum_size <= 1122610116
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d975cd5c65a182eea6c722ab1f1db98c).